# Cannot compile c++ software with sqlite3.h

Tags: c++, sqlite, compilation

I want to compile a code that uses `<sqlite3.h>` with a Makefile:

```
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -I../../bin/include -L../../bin/lib/ -lsqlite3 

all : evolve move_to_db 

evolve :

clean :
    rm -f *.o evolve move_to_db
```

with gcc version:

```
g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

It fails with error:

```
$ make
g++ -std=c++11 -I../../bin/include -L../../bin/lib/ -lsqlite3     evolve.cpp   -o evolve
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccANBfuV.o: in function `check_exist(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
evolve.cpp:(.text+0x8129): undefined reference to `sqlite3_open_v2'
/usr/bin/ld: evolve.cpp:(.text+0x8173): undefined reference to `sqlite3_prepare_v2'
/usr/bin/ld: evolve.cpp:(.text+0x818d): undefined reference to `sqlite3_bind_int64'
/usr/bin/ld: evolve.cpp:(.text+0x81a4): undefined reference to `sqlite3_bind_int64'
/usr/bin/ld: evolve.cpp:(.text+0x81e0): undefined reference to `sqlite3_bind_text'
/usr/bin/ld: evolve.cpp:(.text+0x821c): undefined reference to `sqlite3_bind_text'
/usr/bin/ld: evolve.cpp:(.text+0x8236): undefined reference to `sqlite3_bind_int64'
/usr/bin/ld: evolve.cpp:(.text+0x8272): undefined reference to `sqlite3_bind_text'
/usr/bin/ld: evolve.cpp:(.text+0x8282): undefined reference to `sqlite3_step'
/usr/bin/ld: evolve.cpp:(.text+0x82a2): undefined reference to `sqlite3_finalize'
/usr/bin/ld: evolve.cpp:(.text+0x82ae): undefined reference to `sqlite3_close_v2'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [<builtin>: evolve] Error 1
```

It compiles without problems with gcc

```
g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

on my other machine.

Comment: Without saying `libsqlite3` exists in directory `../../lib/`

Comment: I think you need to add lib `sqlite` to the end of the command line. By the time you process `evolve.cpp`, the symbols in the lib have already been dropped.

Comment: It is a linking and not a compiling errors. Linking errors happen either if you don’t linkt to a required library or if the header that it included it from a different and incompatible version of the library to which you are linking to.

Comment: Why are you putting libraries in `CXXFLAGS`? You should review your Makefile reference again...